# `self.bounds.size.width` in lazy instantiation of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cgrect

Instantiating a UILabel lazily with `self.bounds.size.width` throws an error.

```
lazy public var nameLabel = {
    return UILabel (frame: CGRect(10, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 40))
}
```

The error says: `Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> TableViewCell' has no member width`.

What replacement for `self.bounds.size.width` is there in terms of a programmatic view for UITableViewCell?

Comment: When you are refering to self inside the initialization of a variable, you are refering to the variable itself, so you are trying to access to something that it is not initialized yet. If you want to initialize with the width of the screen you must call the `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width`

Comment: The cell should not take the width of the `mainScreen()`, since the instance of `UITableView` may be less than `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width`. Is there a way to lazy initialize an instance of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Thanks, @AitorPagán! You helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric, try this way

```
public lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = {
        return UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: 40))
}()
```

or

```
public lazy var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: 40))
```

Comment: There it is! Xcode did not autocomplete these methods.

Comment: I toggled `.init` after `CGRect`; adding / deleting `.init` does not throw an error in the compiler. Do you have any idea what the difference is?

Comment: There is no really differences. Sometimes you need to type .init in meta types.

Comment: You can also just say `public lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: 40))`